# How do I set permissions on my VSTO outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I am trying to distribute my Outlook Add-In to the rest of the company.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional and Outlook 2003. In VS I used an installed template for Outlook 2003. It created a solution with BOTH a project and an installer.

I use the project and created an Add-In. **It works GREAT on my PC in development**. Now, I want to distribute it. Here's where things go haywire. The nice little installer they provide DOESN'T ACTUALLY WORK.

The installer runs and places the files where they are to go, but the add-in doesn't run. Instead it gets errors about not having permissions. The installer didn't automatically set the security settings for you.

No problem. You just have to set those settings... right? But no where can I find a simple list of those settings.

I've been to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051.aspx a thousand times from almost every possible link on the web. I've read every Microsoft paper that I can find on VSTO add-Ins. Unfortunately everything seems to reference some magic script... "Just include the sample code..."

[rant] IF A SECTION OF CODE OR AN ENTIRE SOLUTION IS REQUIRED TO DISTRIBUTE YOUR CODE IT IS *NOT* SAMPLE!! IT IS REQUIRED !!! [/rant]

There. I feel better.

Since I installed VS2008, I don't have the directory:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office SE Resources\Samples

No problem, right? Just DL it from microsoft. I've downloaded every "vstor.exe" that I can get my hands on. They all offer to "repair or uninstall" my current installation, but no matter what I choose, the vstor.exe crashes.

HELP!!!

I just want to know what I need to do (the manual steps, if necessary!!!!!) to get my friggin app distributed.

No magic "include this gizmo". No fifty-thousand page diatribes.

Anyone know how this is ACTUALLY done?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

I was able to get a "sample code" update from Microsoft that allowed me to follow the walk-through.

I still think that's utterly ridiculous to HAVE to use sample code to easily distribute your app. However it is working at the moment.

The link I used was given to me by anonymous use on a different board. Whoever you are THANK YOU!!!!

Here is the link I was given:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6991E869-8D5B-45F4-91E7-B527BD236F4C&displaylang=en

This allowed me to actually get my hands on that mysterious "sample" code even though I use VS2008 Professional.

Comment: This anonymous user just went to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332052.aspx (Deploying Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the Office System SE Solutions Using Windows Installer: Walkthroughs (Part 2 of 2)) and got the first link. I know is frustrating to work with VSTO (I did my share of add-ins for Outlook2007 and Project2003), but it was pretty easy to find the "mysterious sample code". ;D