# VSTO: Install an add-in to Outlook Office 2003

Tags: outlook, vsto, distribution, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I posted an article here ([How do I set permissions on my VSTO outlook add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095195/how-do-i-set-permissions-on-my-vsto-outlook-add-in)) and I was able to build my installer. I thought that once the installer built itself, everything would work fine.

I was wrong. It works on about half of the PC's I've run the installer on. My problem is that the other half doesn't work. I'm trying to install an add-in to Outlook Office 2003.

I've even gone so far as to create the steps manually by using a batch file. Nothing seems to work on these PCs and I can't find a common denominator that I can rule out or in that will make the VSTO Addin work.

Here is the batch file I am using. What am I doing/not-doing wrong with this?

I could really use a VSTO expert's help. Thanks!!!!

**EDIT** I've changed the batch file and registry settings to reflect recent updates to them. I've also attached the error text that comes from the PCs that don't work.

```
@echo off

echo Installing Visual Studio for Office Runtime (SE 2005)...
..\VSTO\vstor.exe

echo Creating Directories...
mkdir "c:\program files\Project Archiver"

echo Installying Add-In... 
echo Copying files...
xcopy /Y *.dll "c:\program files\Project Archiver"
xcopy /Y *.manifest "c:\program files\Project Archiver"

echo Setting Security...
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -polchgprompt off
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -u -ag All_Code -url "c:\program files\Project Archiver\ProjectArchiver.dll" FullTrust -n "Project Archiver" -d "Outlook plugin for archiving"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -u -ag All_Code -url "c:\program files\Project Archiver\Microsoft.Office.Interop.SmartTags.dll" FullTrust -n "Project Archiver" -d "Outlook plugin for archiving"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe" -polchgprompt on

echo Loading Registry Values...
"c:\program files\Project Archiver\VSTO_settings.reg"

echo "That should do it."
pause
```

I took the Registry settings (mentioned in the batch file above) straight from a PC that this application worked on. The VSTO Registry settings I am using are :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ProjectArchiver\CLSID]
@="{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}]
@="ProjectArchiver -- an addin created with VSTO technology"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\InprocServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
  00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,53,00,68,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,64,\
  00,5c,00,56,00,53,00,54,00,4f,00,5c,00,38,00,2e,00,30,00,5c,00,41,00,64,00,\
  64,00,69,00,6e,00,4c,00,6f,00,61,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,00,00
"ManifestName"="ProjectArchiver.dll.manifest"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"ManifestLocation"="C:\\Program Files\\Project Archiver\\"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\ProgID]
@="ProjectArchiver"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\Programmable]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="ProjectArchiver"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ProjectArchiver]
@=""





[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}]
@="ProjectArchiver -- an addin created with VSTO technology"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\InprocServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
  00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,53,00,68,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,64,\
  00,5c,00,56,00,53,00,54,00,4f,00,5c,00,38,00,2e,00,30,00,5c,00,41,00,64,00,\
  64,00,69,00,6e,00,4c,00,6f,00,61,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,00,00
"ManifestName"="ProjectArchiver.dll.manifest"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"ManifestLocation"="C:\\Program Files\\Project Archiver\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\ProgID]
@="ProjectArchiver"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\Programmable]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="ProjectArchiver"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ProjectArchiver]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ProjectArchiver\CLSID]
@="{27830B8D-F7A1-4945-AC4A-47661B9ED36D}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\ProjectArchiver]
"Manifest"="C:\\Program Files\\Project Archiver\\ProjectArchiver.dll.manifest"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
"FriendlyName"="ProjectArchiver"
"Description"="ProjectArchiver -- an addin created with VSTO technology"
"CommandLineSafe"=dword:00000001
```

The error I get is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'
   at ProjectArchiver.ThisAddIn.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.CreateStartupObject(EntryPoint entryPoint, Dependency dependency, Assembly objectAssembly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.ConfigureAppDomain()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.LoadAssembliesAndConfigureAppDomain(IHostServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.LoadEntryPointsHelper(IHostServiceProvider serviceProvider)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.816
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.816
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
ProjectArchiver
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Callidus/Project%20Archiver/ProjectArchiver.DLL
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: For those interested, I've noted ALL of the steps I had to take to get this working:

http://www.jerryandcheryl.net/jspot/2009/07/vsto-with-outlook-2003.html

Comment: Jerry's link has been moved to http://jspot.jerryhanel.com/2009/07/21/vsto-with-outlook-2003/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so apparently the AddIn gets automatically disabled by Outlook. Another answer with a slightly different take:

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment 
Variables -> System Variables, and add VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS with a value of 0. This will display error messages on screen, as opposed to silently disabling the VSTO. If you'd rather have a log to disk, add VSTO_LOGALERTS and set it to 1.

Hopefully this will provide you with some extra detail that might help us solve your issue!

Comment: After seeing this error, I've discovered something... Although IT swore that the PIA was auto-installed on everyone's machine... it wasn't.

I put the PIA installer as part of my install script, and (although there are now more buttons to click), it works 100% of the time. 

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR HELPING ME!!

(p.s. for those looking, you can find the PIA installer for 2003 at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3c9a983a-ac14-4125-8ba0-d36d67e0f4ad&displaylang=en)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for having to go through the steps one by one as opposed to having an answer ready, but I'm glad you worked it out... well done!

Answer (score 2):

To start with something trivial: on the PC's where things didn't work, did you check the registry to see if all the entries were properly added? For instance, did the .bat file get run under an account that is actually allowed writing to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?

Are any of those PC's running Vista? Could it be they are running the Office suite without UAC, or with a full administrator account? In that case, the entries should be added to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

**Edit**

Ok, if you are sure things are added to the registry properly, next up is [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) (or procmon if you so prefer). Fire up regmon, start the office host application, and see where it is and isn't looking for the VSTO add-in. Start off with a filter based on your add-in name, then widen up or narrow down depending on the amount of data.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been twisting myself in knots to get this done. To answer your questions:
1) The users are administrators on their own boxes. 
2) I've moved things to HKLM from HKCU. 
3) Since administrators they were able to write to HKCR. I verified those entries on several PCs.

Still... no luck. I'm going insane.

Comment: Just verified the OS version number of all of the PC's in question (if that helps):

Operating system: XP Professional (5.1, build 2600) Service pack 2.

Office Version: Office Professional 2003 (Outlook 2003 ver 11.8206.8221 SP3)

Comment: I've used RegMon to see what is happening on the PCs that work vs. the PCs that don't. They both access the same set of registry entries. Both get "SUCCESSFUL" on the same lines. The only difference is that the PCs that don't work immediately set the LoadBehavior from 3 to 2. (disabled). Did I set the permissions in the CASPOL line correctly?? I assume that I did based on Microsoft forum sites.